# How can I connect to the Lightning Network on Litecoin's testnet?

Tags: litecoin, lightning-network

I installed the software but cannot find any nodes to connect to on testnet. There is a website with mainnet nodes but not testnet. Does anyone know where I can find some testnet nodes?

Answer (score 1):

If you go onto IRC #litecoin-dev and ask for pwkad, I believe he is running one.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment

Comment: While brief, this answer seems to address the askers question. It could be improved, however, by providing more detailed information, such as the actual connection details of pwkad's node.